# Multiple computers with a standard iPhone developer program

Tags: iphone, provisioning, certificate-authority

I have enrolled on the standard iPhone Developer Program and I've successfully created a provisioning profile for my iMac. But I also have a MacBook Pro that I use to work while I'm traveling. But with the standard iPhone Developer Program there seems to be no way to have 2 computers to work, unless I spend time revoking and re-creating/re-validating certification authorities when switching machines.

Am I right? Or is there some way to use the same CA across multiple machines?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just copy your certificate to all of the computers. You will need to export the private part of the certificate, not just the public part.

Comment: Agreed. As far as I know, none of the authentication setup looks at which computer you are developing on.

Comment: Does this still work? I am having troubles enabling two machines for my account. Thanks,EL

Answer (score 12):

You can export your iPhone Development Certificates from Keychain.app as .p12 Files and then import them into the Keycahin.app on your other computer

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

iPhone SDK development on multiple computers
Sometimes it's good to be able to use several computers to develop your iPhone app. In my case my main development machine is the iMac, but summer is coming up and I may not want to stop developing just because I go out of town. Luckily I have a MacBook, on which I have also installed the iPhone SDK.

In order to test on the device when I develop using the MacBook I have to move my certificate, private key and provisioning profile to it. Here's how I do that.

1. Launch Keychain Access on the iMac (main development computer).
2. Under the Keys category I Ctrl-click the private key that has the certificate for 'iPhone Developer: ' attached to it.
3. In the context menu select 'Export ...'.
4. When saving provide a password, which will be required for importing on the other computer.
5. A .p12 file was saved, transfer it to the target computer.
6. Grab the development provisioning profile (either by downloading from the iPhone Program Portal or by grabbing the right one from ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/) and transfer it to the target computer.
7. Double click the .p12 file on the target computer. If you provide the correct password the key and certificate will be installed into the Keychain on the target computer.
8. Drag the provisioning profile onto the Xcode dock icon.

The application can now be installed on the device from the target computer, which in my case is the lovely black MacBook.

Taken From  http://www.theevilboss.com/2009/06/iphone-sdk-development-on-multiple.html

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to explain steps for **export** and **import** certificates

**Export:**

1. Open “Keychain Access”  from your Applications > Utilities folder on your Mac
2. Look for the “Category” area within Keychain Access (left column, below “Keychains”
3. Then look for “iPhone Distribution: [name]” then expand it and highlight both the “iPhone Distribution…” row and the next row, which is the “team agent name” private key
4. While both rows are highlighted, right click and select “Export 2 items” in order to share
5. You will be saving a p12 file to your machine, and you will need to create a password for it in order to share the file (use a good password and remember the password, because you will need to share the password as well)
6. You are free to send both the P12 file and the password to your team member!

The next step is to **install the p12 file on your team member’s system** and get going! Here are the steps…

1. Double click on p12 file that your team member sent you. Keychain Access will open.
2. Enter password you were given… if you don’t have the password, go get it!
3. This will give you a new new private key.
4. Then login to “Team Agent” account on https://developer.apple.com/ and select the Select “iOS Provisioning Profile” link
5. Select Certificates and then Development tab and download and install certificate for Team Agent (Don’t worry! You are almost there!!!)
6. Select Certificates then Development tab and download to install WWDR intermediate certificate (Double click to install to keychain)
7. Select Certificates then Development tab and download to install WWDR intermediate certificate
8. Select Provisioning and then Distribution tab and download provisioning profile (More specifically the .mobileprovision file )
9. Finally drag onto Xcode icon to install

**DONE!!**

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to follow the steps that [Apple provides](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/export_signing_assets.html)...

It instructs you to export your certs through xcode and reimport through Xcode. Works great, but make sure your username is the same on both computers or it will fail.