# iPhone using same certificate on multiple computers with different accounts

Tags: iphone, certificate, provisioning

I have looked around here to see if somebody has asked this question before but nobody really has the same situation so i would like to now how to do the following:

At home i have an iMac on which i do my iPhone development. I can deploy the application on my own iPhone without any problem.

At work i have a colleague who owns a Macbook Pro and i would like to use my certificate to deploy the application on his iPhone.

The tricky part is that we (of course) have different accounts on the computers and i don't want to create an account on his Macbook Pro just for this.

I have read in several places that you can export the certificate (in my case from my iMac) and import it onto his computer, a detailed description can be found here: http://www.theevilboss.com/2009/06/iphone-sdk-development-on-multiple.html) but does this scenario also work for different accounts?

If not, how can i do this?

A second question (and which might also solve my first question), does every member on the development team need to have a personal account for the Provisioning portal? And thus pay the development fee?, i have a company registration and i can register 100 devices but when i want to add a person using the Member center i get the feeling that this person needs to register himself first and pay the development fee)

Comment: You can refer to my answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51815604/1872233

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

First:  add your buddy to your 'team' in the iphone developer portal.  he then will have to generate his own certificates.  There is no additional charge for this.  This makes sense if you want to give him source code and let him use Xcode to work with / debug the app.  If you don't want to give him source code, do the second choice.

Second: if he doesn't need to debug and use Xcode, just add his phone UUID to your 'Devices' in the portal, generate an Ad Hoc Distribution Certificate and then make an Ad Hoc build for anything you want to give him to test/try out.  He then just uses itunes to copy the ad hoc certificate and the app to his phone.  There are instructions in the portal for making the ad hoc builds.

Comment: Your first solution is perfect, i thought i had to go through the whole registration process like i did during a payed registration but as turned out you can just add new developers on the fly..

Answer (score 2):

The quickest smartes and easiest solution.

Saved me hours of searching and implemnting different tactics and techniques

[iphone sdk development on multiple mac machines](http://www.theevilboss.com/2009/06/iphone-sdk-development-on-multiple.html)