# Apple Development Certificate

Tags: iphone, certificate, ipod

To test the iPhone application in the physical device are needed to obtain the Apple  Development Provisioning Profile in iPod and Development Certificate in the MAC.

My question is if the Development Certificate in the MAC can be installed in many MAC or you can install only a single MAC.

What about the certificate for the iPod goes the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple computers with a standard iPhone developer program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853304/multiple-computers-with-a-standard-iphone-developer-program)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the developer certificate - as the name says - is bound to a developer, not a device. When you've dann all the steps in the provisioning portal to obtain your certificate (One hint: You have to use Safari to upload the Certificate Signing Request. That took me quite some time to figure that out) and have imported your profile to Xcode you can easily export your certificate into a password protected zip-file and move it to another mac.

==> So you can have one developer profile on multiple machines and you can also have multiple developer profiles on one machine

For the devices you don't really have a certificate. You need to add the devices to your developer account (This can easily be done from within Xcode) and than you have to create a provisioning profile for your apps. When you create that profile you can select which devices you want to include in that profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the developer certificate in any MAC , but for each developer certificate you can only get 99 devices provisioned ... So that developer ceertificate will only let you test and debug only on those 99 devices.. hope this helps...